# Wordpress - Unable to Shift image or text to the far left or right

Tags: html, css, wordpress, plugins

I'm coding my site manually in a staging environment, and have noticed that I'm unable to manually shift an image or text to the far left or right.

A bit of a back story, I've been coding for about a year now and at the beginning used a plugin to help with my CSS tweaks called 'storefront powerpack'. But now as I'm more experienced, I want to do the CSS more by myself, but what I'm noticing is that when I switch this plugin off, the left and right seem to reveal a 'margin' of some sort. So I can't actually position my text or images to the left past a certain point.

Here is an example below
[image]

As you can see here, there is a massive space to the left that I can't move the image past. I have a feeling that this is to do with the layout and there are hidden side navigations. If this is the case, how do I remove them altogether? How comes the plugin got rid of them but I can't?

Look forward to your help on this - Wonderful stack overflow community!

Comment: Link us your website and your problem will be fixed much much quicker than if we all had to guess :)

Comment: Hi Ricky, my live website is www.cutepinkboutique.com but the one I'm referring to is in staging. The weblink won't work. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you coding a new theme from top to bottom? Or are you adding new bits here and there to an existing theme? This looks like there's existing HTML/CSS that you're fighting. Without the actual code you're not going to get any **good** answers. Please provide a [**Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Very good comment hungerstar. I found that the following CSS 
    @media (min-width: 768px)
      (index):46
       .col-full {
       max-width: 90%;

Was required to get this to work. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to some guidance from hungerstar. I found that the following CSS 
    @media (min-width: 768px)
      (index):46
       .col-full {
       max-width: 90%;

Was required to get this to work. Thank you.